# How to generate a tree (parent-child) in json format from a map

Tags: go, data-structures, tree

**What do I want?**

To get a tree in JSON format from a Map.

**Data to be used:**

A map (key-value pairs), having keys as parents and their respective values as children

**Code:**
The following code uses sample data, I want to use big data later on means having more parents-children. How can I structure parent-child from a Map? Please let me know if I need any other information to parse Map data into a tree structure?

```
type Nodes struct  {
      fn string
      children []*Nodes
}

func main() {
    var m map[string][]string
    m = make(map[string][]string)
    //map of parents(key) and child(values)
    m["root_node"] = []string{"1","2","3","4"}
    m["1"] = []string{"5","6"}
    m["2"] = []string{"7"}
    m["3"] = []string{"8", "9"}
    m["5"] = []string{"10"}
    m["7"] = []string{"11"}
    m["8"] = []string{"12","13"}

//json format: I don't know how to get root_node so expected result can be achieved
bytes, err := json.Marshal(root_node)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
}
```

**My expectation:**

```
{
   "Funcname": "root_node",
   "Nodes": [
      {
         "Funcname": "1",
         "Nodes": [
            {
               "Funcname": "5",
               "Nodes": [
                  {
                     "Funcname": "10",
                     "Nodes": null
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Funcname": "6",
               "Nodes": null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Funcname": "2",
         "Nodes": [
            {
               "Funcname": "7",
               "Nodes": [
                  {
                     "Funcname": "11",
                     "Nodes": null
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Funcname": "3",
         "Nodes": [
            {
               "Funcname": "8",
               "Nodes": [
                  {
                     "Funcname": "12",
                     "Nodes": null
                  },
                  {
                     "Funcname": "13",
                     "Nodes": null
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Funcname": "9",
               "Nodes": null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Funcname": "4",
         "Nodes": null
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a `Node` type with `AddChild()` method -

```golang
type Node struct {
    Fn       string  `json:"Funcname"`
    Children []*Node `json:"Nodes"`
}

func (node *Node) AddChild(child *Node) {
    node.Children = append(node.Children, child)
}
```

A constructor function to construct a new node for given `fn` -

```golang
func CreateNewNode(fn string) *Node {
    newNode := new(Node)
    newNode.Fn = fn
    return newNode
}
```

To generate a tree from map define `MakeTreeFromMap()`function as follows -

```golang
// MakeTreeFromMap generates a tree from given map and returns pointer to root node of tree.
func MakeTreeFromMap(treeMap map[string][]string, rootNodeFn string) *Node {
    cache := make(map[string]*Node)
    for fn, children := range treeMap {
        if _, nodeExists := cache[fn]; !nodeExists {
            node := CreateNewNode(fn)
            cache[fn] = node
        }
        for _, childFn := range children {
            if _, childExists := cache[childFn]; !childExists {
                child := CreateNewNode(childFn)
                cache[childFn] = child
            }
            cache[fn].AddChild(cache[childFn])
        }
    }
    return cache[rootNodeFn]
}
```

Serialize tree into JSON -

```golang
root_node := MakeTreeFromMap(m, "root_node")
bytes, err := json.Marshal(root_node)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

See [Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/MKRMROailFg) for full working example.

Answer (score 1):

### easier approach

We can also say that it is cleaner approach, to construct nodes with constructor syntax.

```
type Node struct {
    Name     string
    Children []*Node
}

func first_example() {
    root := Node{
        Name: "1",
        Children: []*Node{
            {
                Name: "3",
                Children: []*Node{
                    {
                        Name: "5",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

### harder approach

The output is the same but its lot more dynamic and allows you to store additional values, On the other hand traversing the tree is lot more annoying as you have to always cast everything.

```
func second_example() {
    root := map[string]interface{}{
        "Name": "1",
        "Children": []map[string]interface{}{
            {
                "Name": "3",
                "Children": []map[string]interface{}{
                    {
                        "Name": "5",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

### output

```json
{"Name":"1","Children":[{"Name":"3","Children":[{"Name":"5","Children":null}]}]} // #1
{"Children":[{"Children":[{"Name":"5"}],"Name":"3"}],"Name":"1"} // #2
```

### edit

In addition here is the function to insert a node to the structure. False is returned if operation fails.

```
func (n *Node) InsertNode(path string, o *Node) bool {
    parts := strings.Split(path, " ")
    target := n
    for _, part := range parts {
        found := false
        for _, child := range target.Children {
            if child.Name == part {
                target = child
                found = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !found {
            return false
        }
    }

    target.Children = append(target.Children, o)
    return true
}

func third_example() {
    root := &Node{Name: "1"}
    root.Children = append(root.Children, &Node{Name: "3"})
    root.InsertNode("3", &Node{Name: "5"})

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to traverse over map and then create tree nodes without need to put every value manually in a structure. May be by using range or recursion which I am very confused about.

Comment: So you want a method on node that can insert new node not only to top level?

Comment: yes, I want a method which can add data from map to the nodes and then traversing those nodes to form hierarchy then finally display the hierarchy as json.

Comment: @user248396 I added the solution